# Using Appium to test multiple activities

Tags: android, appium

My app contains multiple activities. The flow is:

SplashScreen -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> ?

Activity 1 has a button that leads to Activity 2.

Activity 2 has an editText (must fill) and then a button that leads to Activity 3.

Activity 3 has buttons that lead to the rest of the app

What my code currently does is:

```
    //Define WebDriver
    dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Activity 1
    dr.findElement(By.id("com.package.name:id/btnLoginWithEmail")).click();

    //Activity2
    dr.findElement(By.id("com.package.name:id/emailField")).clear();
    dr.findElement(By.id("com.package.name:id/emailField")).sendKeys("user@domain.com");
    dr.findElement(By.id("com.package.name:id/btnVerifyEmail")).click();
```

To my understanding, Appium will always try to find the element in the current running activity, even if it's the SplashScreen. If it will fail, it will try again and again. My questions are:

1. How do I detect the current running activity?
2. How do I take the current activity into consideration? I see no point in Appium trying to find elements if they do not exist in the current context.

Essentially, the question I'm asking is: What is the correct way to test a certain flow of your app in case there is more than one activity?

I tried to find sample codes, but I couldn't find one for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an answer for your first question is to use `driver.currentActivity()`

We should never bother about the current activity of an application. Better write code which will simply check element is available or not in the current context.
Alright if your requirement is to first verify activity then look for an element then use `String currentActivity=driver.currentActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

You should write test cases in same way as real user interact with your application. During simulation if need scrolling then use Appium scroll function to get exact element of activity.